# Node creation using cypher Foreach

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 csv files and their sructure is as follows:

```
1.csv
id name age
1  aa   23
2  bb   24

2.csv
id product location
1  apple   CA
2  samsung PA
1  HTC     AR
2  philips CA
3  sony    AR

// 1.csv
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///G:/1.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (a:first { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name, age: csvLine.age})

// 2.csv
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///G:/2.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (b:second { id: toInt(csvLine.id), product: csvLine.product, location: csvLine.location})
```

Now i want to create another node called "third", using the following cypher query.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///G:/1.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH c = (a:first), d = (b.second)
FOREACH (n IN nodes(c) | 
CREATE (e:third)
SET e.name = label(a) + label(b) + "id"
SET e.origin = label(a)
SET e.destination = label(b)
SET e.param = a.id)
```

But the above query give me duplicate entries. I think here it runs 2 time after the load. Please suggest or any alternative way for this.

Comment: the above query will not even compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE` always creates, even if something is already there.  So that's why you're getting duplicates.  You probably want `MERGE` which only creates an item if it doesn't already exist.

I wouldn't ever do `CREATE (e:third)` or `MERGE (e:third)` because without specifying properties, you'll end up with duplicates anyway.  I'd change this:

```
CREATE (e:third)
SET e.name = label(a) + label(b) + "id"
SET e.origin = label(a)
SET e.destination = label(b)
SET e.param = a.id)
```

To this:

```
MERGE (e:third { name: label(a) + label(b) + "id",
                 origin: label(a), 
                 destination: label(b),
                 param: a.id })
```

This then would create the same node when necessary, but avoid creating duplicates with all the same property values.

[Here's the documentation on `MERGE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html)

Comment: or rather `MERGE (:third {key:key-value}) ON CREATE SET ...`

Answer (score 1):

#### You don't use csvLine at all for matching the :first and :second node!

#### So your query doesn't make sense

This doesn't make sense either:

```
MATCH c = (a:first), d = (b.second)
FOREACH (n IN nodes(c) | 
CREATE (e:third)
```

c are paths with a single node, i.e. (a)
so instead of the foreach you would use `a` directly instead